# Upgrade from 7.16 to 7.19 problem

Tags: updating

I made upgrade from 7.16 version to 7.19, everything works ok, but on *Available updates* it says Installed version is 7.16.

I done everything like drupal update steps say. Removed all old files of drupal core and put new one, made update.php for database.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Go to your website's root directory and open CHANGELOG.txt.  Does it talk about Drupal 7.19 or does it start with 7.16?

Comment: First line in file is:

Drupal 7.19, 2013-01-16

Comment: Run "check available updates" again.

Comment: Run cron, maybe that helps

Comment: I do all that :(